# how to generate dynamic values inside div tag in repeater which are not in database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

i have a table in databse as following

```
seatId,flightId,seatStatus,passengerId,
```

currently i am using a repeater like this to match some values in jquery and store in databse.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SeatingSection" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="seat <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("seatStaus")) ? "available" : "not-available" %>"><%# Eval("SeatId") %></div>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Assuming i have 100 seat for 1 flightID, this requires me to manually insert seatNo and seatStatus in database, or write 100 div's for seatId's for 1 single flightId. What i want to do is to generate 100 seats with different id's and corresponding status without having to type it manually and without entering any prior value in database. how can i do this?
Edit:the data source for repeater is list of type class.is it possible to populate the list to empty values for the ones not yet in database?

Comment: if you don't want to store the seat data in the database, how will you keep track of the seat status? If i'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you just want to use a loop to populate a collection with 100 seat objects and use it for the repeater data source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but it sounds like you could use hidden fields and generate GUIDs for unique IDs. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with jQuery, but you could traverse the DOM using the hidden fields as your starting point to modify the attributes of parent/sibling elements.

```
<div id="item-list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">Heading</div>
        <input type="hidden" id="item1" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">Heading</div>
        <input type="hidden" id="item2" value="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var el = $("#item-list");
    if (el) {
        $(el).find("input:hidden").each(function () {
            $(this).siblings(".item-title").text("Heading " + $(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but in this case I'd have to write 100 cases if i'd have to reach value 100. And as for the loop how do I implement it inside repeater, example please

Answer (score 0):

I have used another approach to solve this thing. Upvote for the answer
I was using List as a dataSource for repeater, and i inserted 100 values in the List rather than the database. In this was i didnt have to populate the database.